# Query with count and group by eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to have a table in the view that shows all the registration types associated with a conference, the price of each one and the number of registrations sold of each registration type.

For example if the conference with id "1" has two registration types with this columns and values:

- rtype1 (name), 0.00$ (price),  20 (capacity)
- rtype2 (name), 5.00$ (price),  10 (capacity)

And there are 20 participants registered in the rtype1 and 5 registered in the rtype 2 I want to show a table like:

```
Registration Type name               Price           Sold/capacity 
rtype1                               0.00$              20/20
rtype2                               5.00$              5/10
```

Im not understanding how to properly achieve that. For now I have this query to get each registration type and the count of each registration type:

```
$participantsOfEachType = Participant::
 select(DB::raw('registration_type_id, count(registration_type_id)'))
->groupBy('registration_type_id')->get();
```

This query returns the results below. But is not considering a specific conference. Do you know what is necessary to consider a specific conference id so is possible to show the results in a table like its in the above table example?

```
Collection {#271 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Participant {#282 ▼
    ...
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "registration_type_id" => 1
        "count(registration_type_id)" => 2
      ]
    ...
    }
    1 => Participant {#279 ▼
    ...
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "registration_type_id" => 2
        "count(registration_type_id)" => 2
      ]
      ... 
    }
  ]
}
```

**Relevant models for the question:**

Users model:

```
public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','user_that_did_registration');
}
```

Registration model:

```
// user that did the registration
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
}
 public function participants(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
}

public function conference(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
}
```

Conference Model:

```
 public function registrations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
}
```

Participants mode:

```
public function registration(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
}

public function registration_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
}
```

Comment: Can you include your models and their relation defined between them or provide table definitions and sample data sets for your tables

Comment: Thanks I update the question with the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `RegistrationType` model have following mappings

```
Class RegistrationType Extends Model{

    public function participants(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Participants','registration_type_id')
    }

}
```

Then for your expected output you could get data as

```
$conference_id = 1;

$registrationTypes = RegistrationType::withCount('participants')
                                    ->whereHas('participants.registration.conference',function($query) use ($conference_id){
                                        $query->where('id','=', $conference_id)
                                    });
                                    ->get();
```

When you loop through your results each row in `$registrationTypes` will have an attribute `participants_count` which will give you the count of participants for that registration type.

[See Counting Related Models & Querying Relationship Existence sections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

try
`select conference_id,
       group_concat(concat_ws(':', registration_type_id, cnt))
from (select conference_id, registration_type_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by conference_id, registration_type_id
     ) tm
group by conference_id
order by conference_id;`

Comment: Thanks, the question is about Eloquent, but with that query it shows a Table  doesn't exist error.

Comment: You just have to replace with your table names